# Insert class into alternate rows in struts grid view

Tags: datagrid, struts2, grid

Is there any method to insert the different class into alternate rows in struts2 datagrid. using the altClass property i can insert class into either even or odd rows. But i want to insert different class for odd rows and even rows. Is it possible in struts2 drid view

Comment: But how can i accept answers? By doing upVote?

Comment: select answer which has helped you by clicking answer as accepted.Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9086686/how-data-travels-in-struts2 it has been accepted by the OP (see green mark indicating accepted)

Comment: Find the underlying JS datagrid and use it directly... I can't express how much these UI tag questions drive me crazy.

Comment: Yah i have download the css and use it directly. Now it is working

Comment: +1 just because you did the right thing.

Comment: Sorry I like to see closed questions.  If you could self answer this question and state simply what you did to solve it I would upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I have just download the ui.jquery.css and include it manually in my jsp page using link tag. And i have use `altRows="true"` and `altClass="even"` and access this even class different style and other `<tr>` without even class other style. That's it.